# How to get previous element zero or more times, but as few times as possible?

Tags: regex

My input is: `abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4`

I wont to get `a`, and any chars **but as few times as possible**, and `3`.

the output must begins with `a`, and continues with every character in the world except for something corresponding to `a`, and ending with `3`, where `a` is a Regax expression.

but if I use pattern: `a.*?3`, the match is: `abc1 abc2 abc3`, But I expecting to `abc3`.

I can't use `a[^a]*?3` because `a` is unknown in advance.

How can I achieve this in .NET Regex?

Comment: Why not `\w` or `\S` instead of `.`? You say "a is unknown in advance", what is it? If yu have `(\w+)` then use `(?:(?!\1).)*`

Comment: You could do `.*(a.*?3)`. The desired result would be in Group 1

Comment: Can you please tell what output you are expecting? You are not very clear when you say - `a, and any chars but as few times as possible, and 3`

Comment: Maybe something like: `\ba\S*?3`

Comment: @404 in `abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4, abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4` I get just last `abc3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match some generic pattern, then match any text that does not match the value pattern up to the leftmost occurrence of the right-hand delimiter pattern.

In this case you need do

- [Capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the starting pattern into a group
- Use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) with the backreference to the group value as the negative lookahead pattern, make sure the quantifier is non-greedy

Here is an example with `a` starting delimiter pattern that is obfuscated as `(?![b-z])[a-z]`:

```
((?![b-z])[a-z])(?:(?!\1).)*?3
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GzDlHV/1). So, it matches

- `((?![b-z])[a-z])` - Capturing group 1: any lowercase ASCII but a letter from `b` to `z` range (basically, `a`)
- `(?:(?!\1).)*?` - any char, but a newline char, 0 or more occurrences (but as few as possible), that does not start the value stored in Group 1
- `3` - the right-hand delimiter, `3`.